# Creating a function that returns a list of 5 cards drawn from a shuffled deck without replacement

Tags: python, random

I am creating a function that returns a list of 5 cards drawn from a shuffled deck without replacement. I have to run function 10000 times and calculate the number of times where the 5 cards contain 4 of the same kind, for example: ['2 of Spades', '3 of Clubs', '2 of Diamonds', '2 of Spades', '2 of Hearts']. Below is the code I Have so far

```
import random


suits = ['Spades','Clubs','Hearts','Diamonds']
cards = list('23456789JQKA')
cards.insert(8,'10')
deck = [card+' of '+suit for card in cards for suit in suits]


def draw_wo_replacement(deck):
    for i in range (5):
        newdeck=[]
        index = random.randint(0,len(deck)-1)
        card = deck[index]
        deck.pop(index)
        newdeck.append(card)
    return newdeck
print(draw_wo_replacement(deck))
```

The new deck I am trying to print only comes out with one value, not sure why the loop is not working. And I am unsure of how I could run this 10000 or how to calculate the number of times where the 5 cards contain 4 of the same kind

Comment: Because you're recreating the list *inside the loop*; think it through.

Comment: Since you are already using the `random` module, you might as well use `random.sample(deck, 5)` to pick five card from the deck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to return a list in your `draw_wo_replacement` function. So you must create an empty list at first and append what you want to that and then return new list. But what you are doing in this function, is creating new list in each iteration and append new card to it. So it will return a list with one card at the end. (the last card of cards you want. you must know why now)

Just change your funnction to this:

```py
def draw_wo_replacement(deck):
    newdeck=[]
    for i in range (5):
        index = random.randint(0,len(deck)-1)
        card = deck[index]
        deck.pop(index)
        newdeck.append(card)
    return newdeck
```